# How to create IEnumerable<T> on which multiple enumerations are not possible?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

When I enumerate over an IEnumerable twice Resharper complains about `Possible multiple enumerations of IEnumerable`. I know, in some case of DB-queries when you enumerate twice you get an exception.

I want to reproduce that behavior in tests. So, I basically want the following function to throw (because of multiple enumerations):

```
    private void MultipleEnumerations(IEnumerable<string> enumerable)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(enumerable.Count().ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(enumerable.Count().ToString());
    }
```

What should I pass to it? All the Lists, Collections etc. are ok with multiple enumerations.
Even this kind of IEnumerable doesn't give an exception:

```
    private IEnumerable<string> GetIEnumerable()
    {
        yield return "a";
        yield return "b";
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just want a custom class:

```
public class OneShotEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _source;
    private bool _shouldThrow = false;

    public OneShotEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        this._source = source;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_shouldThrow) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        _shouldThrow = true;

        return _source.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your own class that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and throw an exception if `GetEnumerator()` is called twice (use a boolean instance field).

Alternatively, create an iterator that uses a flag field to ensure that it cannot be called twice (enumerating an iterator twice will execute the entire method twice).

Comment: The problem with using a flag in an iterator is that the state would have to be attached to the class in which the iterator exists, rather than on the enumerable itself.

Comment: flag is a good way if you want a one-time solution, thanks. Class is better, and flag is quicker :)

Answer (score 1):

The custom class, which I've copied from John Gietzen's answer (with a couple of corrections), could usefully be combined with an extension method to create a really simple way to do this.

```
public class OneShotEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> source;
    private bool shouldThrow = false;

    public OneShotEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (shouldThrow) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This enumerable has already been enumerated.");

        shouldThrow = true;

        return this.source.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public static clas OneShotEnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SingleUse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
#if (DEBUG)
        return new OneShotEnumerableExtension(source);
#else
        return source;
#endif
    }
}
```

Then you can pass something to your previous method by simply doing

```
MultipleEnumerations(MyEnumerable.SingleUse());
```